# Crossed Words Puzzle

Tags: crosswords

This is a small puzzle, I don't think it should be too hard and it doesn't have a "final answer" word or phrase.

I made this in response to a challenge that my friend who first showed me this site gave me, and I think it worked out really well!

If solving the puzzle itself isn't hard enough, then I can "pass on" the challenge. What can you come up with in a similar style? It doesn't have to be the same size or shape, and you can fudge the rules if you want. You can reply with the answer to this one, or your own attempt at making one.

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| speak | something | similarly | many | times |
| via |  | made |  | growing |
| expanded | wage | or | bring | up |
| vocal |  | exactly |  | after |
| what | fruits | equal | during | adolescence |

Comment: *what* are the rules? Do we have to fill the blanks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each row across and down is a clue for the word going in that square.

```
CHANT
O L E
RAISE
D K N
SEEDS
```